# Ubuntu 13.10 won't suspend

Tags: 13.10, suspend, acpi, wpa-supplicant

Have been thru several threads with similar issues, but no resolution. ASUS X201E, freshly upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10. Suspend from any menu does not work since upgrade. When I select "Suspend" from the top right-hand menu, the screen goes black for a second, then wakes right back up. /var/log/pm-suspend.log is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6577211/

Significant chunk:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager suspend suspend:
Having NetworkManager put all interaces to sleep...Failed.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
```

I get SIGSEGV crashes from wpa_supplicant (and plymouthd) on boot. Suspend DOES work via these commands, cribbed from another thread:

```
sudo bash -c "echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk"
sudo bash -c "echo mem > /sys/power/state"
```

But I don't know why / what this means. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same messages as well, but they don't prevent my system from suspending. There surely is another reason.

The culprit seems to be

```
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3: 9: /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind: Directory nonexistent
/etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3: 9: /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind: Directory nonexistent
/etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 suspend suspend: Returned exit code 2.

Sun Dec 15 03:54:24 CST 2013: Inhibit found, will not perform suspend
```

which seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/linux/+bug/1157435). It is marked "fixed" so you may just need to `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to install an updated kernel, but some commenters still experience a problem without the workaround described in [comment #22](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/linux/+bug/1157435/comments/22).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for this, unfortunately for me this hook runs fine on my system (`Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 suspend suspend: /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 suspend suspend: success.`) The only part that seems to fail for me is NetworkManager / wpa_supplicant.

Comment: Then what is this in http://paste.ubuntu.com/6577211/ on lines 15478 and 15606? According to your log the hooks fails during the latest instances of suspend and hibernate.

Comment: Hmmmmm guess I overlooked it! Thanks for pointing that out. I followed the workaround in comment #22 (sudo rm /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3) and I now have suspend working! It is slightly odd - goes black, comes back for 5 seconds, then suspends properly - but it works! Thanks much David!